# Create new dataframe reorganizing columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have looked at similar posts but haven't gotten anything to solve my issue.

I have a dataframe (df) with different sizes of two characteristic (S042: 4 sizes, S081: 3 sizes) as variables for 5 individuals (Sample):

```
  Sample S042_91 S042_93 S042_105 S042_107 S081_184 S081_187 S081_188
1   6001      91       0        0      107      184      187        0
2   6002       0      93      105        0        0        0      188
3   6005      91       0      105        0        0        0      188
4   6006       0       0        0      107        0      187      188
5   6008      91       0        0      107       NA       NA       NA
```

I would like to create a new dataframe reorganizing data per characteristic limiting to two columns (since each individual has one or two sizes, no more). If individual has one size, the second column must have a "0". If individual has no sizes (NA), both columns must have "NA". Also, rename characteristic column names to _1 and _2 keeping characteristic name.

New dataframe would end up looking like:

```
  Sample S042_1 S042_2 S081_1 S081_2
1   6001     91    107    184    187
2   6002     93    105    188      0
3   6005     91    105    188      0
4   6006    107      0    187    188
5   6008     91    107     NA     NA
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So to be clear: each section (the SO42 section, the SO81 section) is either: all NAs ; exactly one non-zero values; exactly two non-zero values. Other possibilities (three non-zero values, NA plus a value) are impossible?

Comment: You are right. Number of columns for a characteristic is variable, depend on number of different sizes. Columns can include non-zero values and zeros together (at least one non-zero value). NA plus values are not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vector of unique column names that have different prefixes excluding the first column.  This can be done using `gsub` by stripping out the characters starting from the `_`.  Then, loop this using `lapply` and `grep` this pattern to get the columns that have the same prefix.  You can use apply to get the elements that are not `0` for each row followed by 0's.

```
size <- 1:2
nm1 <-  paste0("^", unique(gsub("\\_.*", "", colnames(df)[-1])))
dfN <- cbind(df[,1],do.call(data.frame,
         lapply(nm1, function(x) t(apply(df[grep(x, colnames(df))],1,
                function(x) c(x[x!=0], x[x==0])[size])))))

 colnames(dfN) <- c("Sample", paste(rep(c('SO42', 'SO81'), each=2), 1:2, sep="_"))


 dfN
 #  Sample SO42_1 SO42_2 SO81_1 SO81_2
 #1   6001     91    107   184    187
 #2   6002     93    105   188     0
 #3   6005     91    105   188     0
 #4   6006    107      0   187    188
 #5   6008     91    107    NA    NA
```

Another way using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 df %>% 
    gather(Var, Val, -Sample) %>%
    separate(Var, c("Var1", "Var2")) %>%
    group_by(Sample, Var1) %>% 
    arrange(Val==0) %>%
    slice(1:2) %>%
    mutate(n=row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    unite(Var, Var1, n) %>% 
    select(-Var2) %>% 
    spread(Var, Val)
 #    Sample S042_1 S042_2 S081_1 S081_2
 #1   6001     91    107    184    187
 #2   6002     93    105    188      0
 #3   6005     91    105    188      0
 #4   6006    107      0    187    188
 #5   6008     91    107     NA     NA
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot. I can change dimension of "size" to reorganize in 2, 3, 4... columns. Also, I created an object to collect df's unique column names and rename dfN's column names.

Comment: I missed this post. I have things to learn here. I need more training to be able to write something like your first idea. +1 as usual.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks, If you use `lapply/sapply` frequently, this becomes easier.

Comment: I am getting comfortable with `lapply` and `apply`. I am OK with `sapply`. But I am still behind for `tapply`, `mapply`, for example. Some easy examples in tutorials hardly help. So whenever I see these in SO, I am taking notes. Likewise, I am still observing how `Reduce` and `Map` are used in SO. Any advice for `Reduce` and `Map`?

Comment: @jazzurro `Reduce` is similar to `do.call`.  You can use that on a list.  For example if you want to get the sum of corresponding elements of vectors (for example) from a list, `Reduce(`+`, lst)` assuming that there are no `NAs`.  We can do `Map/mapply` when there are multiple vectors/lists/dataframes` of equal length/dimensions, and you want to do some operation on corresponding elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I recently noticed that `Reduce` and `do.call` are similar. How are `Map` and `mapply` different?

Comment: @jazzurro `Map` returns the output in a list. `mapply` can return the output as matrix when the dimension matches.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I just saw your new `Reduce` answer. Taking notes now.

Comment: I saw a question yesterday and did the following. `x <- c("[0 0.1 0.2 0.4]"); y <- gsub("\\[(.*)\\]", "\\1", x) %>% strsplit(split = " ")`. `do.call(as.numeric, y)` returns a numeric vector whereas `Reduce(as.numeric, y)` returns a character vector. `Reduce` "reduced" a list to a vector, but not to numeric. Why is this the case? I think you will reach 20K this weekend or early next week!

Comment: @jazzurro I wouldn't use either `do.call` or `Reduce` in a list to convert the elements to `numeric`.  You could use `lapply(strsplit(y, split=' '), numeric)` In the example you showed, there is only one element.  Consider one with multiple elements, ie. `lst1 <- list(c("0.1", "0.2"), c("0.5", "0.3"))` And if you apply it with either `Reduce` or `do.call` , the output will be a vector returning only the first list element(but both cases are numeric).  But, `lapply(lst1, as.numeric)` will return both.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks, also you can check http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Reduce-and-do-call-td4677792.html

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much for your advice. The `do.call` idea was the chosen answer for the question. I am glad to hear that you taught me this. I will take a note now. Thanks for the link. That has good info for me. By the way, Ananda found the reason why I have buggy behaviour with splitstackshape. There will be an update soon or later. This was something to do with data.table 1.9.5.

Comment: @akrun I guess you will achieve 20K anytime now. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

```
S4 <- apply(tmp, 1, function (x) sort(x[2:5], decreasing=TRUE)[1:2])
S8 <- apply(tmp, 1, function (x) sort(x[6:8], decreasing=TRUE)[1:2])
newdata <- cbind(t(S4), t(S8))
```

Untested but should work. Renaming the columns and making it a data frame is left for you to do.

Comment: Thanks Dash2. It works but I needed a code to be applied to a large number of characteristics to reorganize into different number of columns. In my example, maximum number of columns per characteristic was 2 but I need to reorganize also in 3, 4 or 5 columns depending on type of samples. Code performed by @Akrun resolved my issue.